# 502 bad gateway ngnix with middleware

Tags: laravel

I have a big problem since two days when i want to refresh the application when the session is finish now i get an error 502 bad gateway ngnix.

It's seems that my middleware group have some problems to work. It's strange because it worked very well but since 2 days it doesn't work anywore .

In my routes file i create a middleware group for all the pages of the applications like :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['AuthVerif']], function () {

    // PAGE ACCEUIL
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    //PROFILE / STRUCTURE / CLUB
    Route::get('profile' , 'UserController@getProfile')->name('profile');
    Route::get('password' , 'UserController@getPassword')->name('password');
    Route::get('ma_structure' , 'StructureController@getMyStructure');
    Route::get('mon_club' , 'ClubController@getMyClub');
```

...

My middleware AuthVerif :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(Auth::guest()){

            return redirect( url('/') );

        }else

        return $next($request);
    }
```

the middleware display the login form to the user.

Someone know why i get

> 502 bad gateway ngnix.

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Following

- Register your middleware in kernel.php -> routeMiddleware
- use Auth() in your middelware file
- give read/write permission to storage and bootstrap folder

Comment: thanks !! how i give red/write permission to storage and bootstrap

Comment: if you are using linux then use following command:
chmod 777 -R folderpath

and if you are using window command then use properties tab to change security permission